# Using `sed` to remove all elements from JSON array

Tags: unix, sed, macos-catalina, darwin

I know StackOverflow is not a code-writing-service, but `sed` has been driving me crazy for the past 3 hours.

In summary, I need to modify the contents of a `.json` file that I have.

**What the file looks like:**

```js
{
// ...
    "first": {
        "second": [
            "indexZero",
            "theseStringsAreDynamic",
            "soINeedToUseWildcard"
        ]
    }
// ...
}
```

**Desired result:**

```js
{
// ...
    "first": {
        "second": [
        ]
    }
// ...
}
```

**What have you done?**

I have tried about a million variations loosely based upon:

```sh
sed -i 's/\"second\": \[.*\]/\"second\": []/' "my.json"

## ~ Which gives: ~
#
#    "first": {
#        "second": []
#            "indexZero",
#            "theseStringsAreDynamic",
#            "soINeedToUseWildcard"
#        ]
#    },
```

Essentially, I need to remove all elements from an array in a `.json` file, so if `sed` is not the correct tool for the job, please let me know.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct tool for the job is [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
$ jq '.first.second = []' input.json
{
  "first": {
    "second": []
  }
}
```

---

To replace the original file, it's a two step process - redirect output to a temporary file and then rename it:

```
jq '.first.second = []' orig.json > tmp.json && mv -f tmp.json orig.json
```